# Left join value of exact date and if missing find previous value

Tags: r, dplyr, left-join

I have two datasets (df1 and df2) that both have the common columns "date" and "country" that are used to left_join the datasets (especially the column "price" from df2). If there is no exact match (date and country), the missing values (NAs) are filled with the value from the previous row (by country). This works quite well so far.

However, I have problems if there is no exact match for the first observation (by country), because then it is not possible to fill it with the previous row. In this case the NA (e.g. row 1; 2015-07-18) should be filled with the previous value from df2, which contains an observation on 2015-07-15. It is important, that I match on the exact date or previous date (latest known value) and not the nearest date, which would be 2017-07-20.

In the final table, the price on 2015-07-18 (UK) should be 2.5, which is the last known value.

Below you will find the current table and exemplary data.

```
   date         country   price
1  2015-07-18   UK        NA  
2  2015-07-20   UK        3.0  
3  2015-07-21   UK        2.7
4  2015-07-22   UK        4.5
5  2015-07-25   UK        4.6
6  2015-07-19   US        1.3
7  2015-07-20   US        2.7
8  2015-07-21   US        3.9
9  2015-07-22   US        2.8
10 2015-07-24   US        2.5
```

```
library(dplyr)

date <- c("2015-07-18", "2015-07-20", "2015-07-21", "2015-07-22", "2015-07-25", "2015-07-19", "2015-07-20",
          "2015-07-21", "2015-07-22", "2015-07-24")
country <- c("UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US")

df1 <- cbind.data.frame(date, country)

date <- c("2015-07-15", "2015-07-20", "2015-07-21", "2015-07-22", "2015-07-24", "2015-07-19", "2015-07-20",
          "2015-07-21", "2015-07-22", "2015-07-24")
country <- c("UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US")
price <- c(2.5, 3.0, 2.7, 4.5, 4.6, 1.3, 2.7, 3.9, 2.8, 2.5)

df2 <- cbind.data.frame(date, country, price)

df <- df1 %>%
  left_join(df2, by = c("date", "country"))

df %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  tidyr::fill(price,.direction ="down") %>%
  arrange(country, date) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: I might try `full_join` first instead of `left_join`, then after you do `fill`, do a `right_join` of `df1` at the end...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `full_join()`

```
df_b <- df1 %>% 
  full_join(df2, by = c("date", "country")) %>% 
  arrange(country, date) %>% 
  group_by(country) %>% 
  mutate(price = ifelse(is.na(price), lag(price), price)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  filter(date %in% df$date) %>% 
  inner_join(df, by = c("date", "country")) %>% 
  select(-price.y)
# A tibble: 10 x 3
# date       country price.x
# <chr>      <chr>     <dbl>
#   1 2015-07-18 UK          2.5
# 2 2015-07-20 UK          3  
# 3 2015-07-21 UK          2.7
# 4 2015-07-22 UK          4.5
# 5 2015-07-25 UK          4.6
# 6 2015-07-19 US          1.3
# 7 2015-07-20 US          2.7
# 8 2015-07-21 US          3.9
# 9 2015-07-22 US          2.8
# 10 2015-07-24 US          2.5
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, this brings me pretty close to where i want to be. The only small error here is that the df now has 11 rows, but it should only have 10 rows (5 per country). The error comes from row 5, because on 2015-07-24 (UK) there should be no entry because there is none in df1 either. It is not filtered out because there is an entry for this date (2015-07-24) for the US. Any suggestions on that?

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I was looking for. Maybe one more point, could you also recommend a way if I have several columns instead of the price. Is there a quick way to do this?

Comment: It's my pleasure if it is helpful for you. At this point, I think we can use the same method if you have several columns. However, I am concerned that there are other better approaches to solve.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option using rolling join in `data.table` (which is shorter and should be much faster):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)
df1[, price := df2[.SD, on=.(country, date), roll=Inf, price]]
```

output:

```
          date country price
 1: 2015-07-18      UK   2.5
 2: 2015-07-20      UK   3.0
 3: 2015-07-21      UK   2.7
 4: 2015-07-22      UK   4.5
 5: 2015-07-25      UK   4.6
 6: 2015-07-19      US   1.3
 7: 2015-07-20      US   2.7
 8: 2015-07-21      US   3.9
 9: 2015-07-22      US   2.8
10: 2015-07-24      US   2.5
```

data:

```
date <- as.Date(c("2015-07-18", "2015-07-20", "2015-07-21", "2015-07-22", "2015-07-25", "2015-07-19", "2015-07-20",
    "2015-07-21", "2015-07-22", "2015-07-24"))
country <- c("UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US")
df1 <- data.frame(date, country)

date <- as.Date(c("2015-07-15", "2015-07-20", "2015-07-21", "2015-07-22", "2015-07-24", "2015-07-19", "2015-07-20",
    "2015-07-21", "2015-07-22", "2015-07-24"))
country <- c("UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US")
price <- c(2.5, 3.0, 2.7, 4.5, 4.6, 1.3, 2.7, 3.9, 2.8, 2.5)
df2 <- data.frame(date, country, price)
```

---

edit: look up for multiple columns:

```
cols <- c("price", "cost", "revenue") 
df1[, (cols) := df2[.SD, on=.(country, date), roll=Inf, mget(cols)]]
```

Comment: This seems to be a really short and quick solution. Does it also work if there are multiple columns in df2? Let us assume there are also the columns cost and revenue? Is there a way to specify all columns?

Comment: Yeah you can use mget to get those columns

Comment: Any suggestions for the specific use of mget in this context? Thanks

Comment: Thanks, exactly as expected and the code is really simple.

Comment: @edmond, you dont have to change the marked answer as you have dplyr tag in your OP. You can just choose the prev ans that you have chosen.

Answer (score 0):

Tho Vu beat me to it, but here is my solution which is very similar:

```
full_join(df1,df2) %>% 
    arrange(country, date) %>% 
    mutate(price=ifelse(is.na(price), lag(price), price))
```